# How can I print the data from the form side by side in the textarea?

Tags: html, forms

I really hope someone can point out my mistake here. This is the code that I have tried.

```
<p>Name :<p id="text1"></p></p>
    <p>Address :<p id="text2"></p></p>
    <p>City :<p id="text3"></p></p>
    <p>E-mail :<p id="text4"></p></p>
```

--The output should display like this --

Name : Jake

Address : Tronoh

City : Perak

E-mail : jake123@gmail.com

--But it turned out to be like this instead --

Name :

Jake

Address :

Tronoh

City :

Perak

E-mail :

jake123@gmail.com

Comment: You shouldn't nest `<p>` tags. Use `<span>` instead

Comment: Okey, wait I`ll try .

Comment: See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cf632Lyb/

Comment: Okey I got it, but I use nested <span> instead of the example code you gave me

Comment: Nested spans are allowed. But you can't nest p tags.

Comment: Noted, thank you for the help.